# Finding full form of parenthesized acronym using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to find full-form of acronyms that have been specified in a text using parenthesis.

Here is an example:

> Aberrant DNA methylation, one of the major epigenetic alterations in cancer, has been reported to accumulate in a subset of colorectal cancer (CRC), so-called CpG island methylator phenotype (CIMP), which was known to correlate with micro satellite reduced instability (MSI)-high CRC

Here, I want to be able to form a list of short-form/full-form occurrences like:

> CRC - Colorectal Cancer
>
> CIMP - CpG island methylator phenotype
>
> MSI - micro satellite reduced instability

The thing is I have been able to find all parenthesized entities using `re.findall('(\(.*?\))', s)`, but finding the corresponding full-form is proving difficult.

Assuming all such full-forms are on the left side of the parenthesis, I want to use the following **2** conditions to capture the full-form of the abbreviation in the parenthesis-

- the number of words be not more than 3+|SF| where |SF| is the number of characters in the short-form (micro satellite reduced instability (MSI) - here the full-form has 4 words whereas the shortform has 3 characters)
- The first word of the full-form start with the first character of the short-form (eg. **c**olorectal cancer (**c**rc))

With my current understanding of `regex`, I have not been able to write a `regex` that solves the above 2 conditions and finds all such cases in the text.

Could you please give me some pointers for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Python :

```
((\w)\w* )(\w* ){0,3}\((?i)(\2)[^)]*\)
```

This one captures the first character of a word in group 2. This word is followed by zero to three words (increase number if suitable). All words are delimited by a literal space. 
Next is an open bracket followed by the letter captured in group 2, which is made case insensitive. All this is followed the rest of the bracket pattern.

I have not been able to match the number of words with the number of characters of the acronym, so one of your conditions is not met.

My comments were too pessimistic. 
But it will catch a lot of nonsense.

Tested on regex101.com

By the way, you could tweak the bracket pattern and use `\([^)]*\)`. Negated characters with greedy multiplier don't need backreference, so the process works faster.